# Unable to write a Where Clause with Linq where data contains an array

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a where clause in Linq that matches on a date. The values for date is contained in a nested object. What I mean is that the object that contains date has two elements start and finish. I am getting two error messages:

1. Cannot implicity convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to bool
2. Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type System.Func because some of the return types in the block are not implicity convertible to the delegate return type

My code is:

```
 var locationName = from relocate in relocations where **relocate.Relocations.
      Where(c=>c.TimeIntervals.Select(d=>d.Start==sh.StartTime.Date))** 
        select relocate.Relocations.Select(a=>a.Path.Items.
             Select(b=>b.DisplayString.Skip(4).SingleOrDefault()));
```

It is the bit which is between the double **.

Please help!!!

Comment: var locationName sound like it is a string or something. But your query returns a `IEnumerable<T>`. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I trying to grab a name which is a string value. It itself is held in array object containing 5 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a disconnect between date and location - I have managed to solve this by using a dictionary class and then matching on the date!

Answer (score 0):

Your `relocate.Relocations.Where` returns IEnumerable. You need to compare (intersect) that with something, such that result evaluates to a boolean.

Perhaps like this:

`relocate.Relocations.Where(...).Any()`

```
var locationName = from relocate in relocations where **relocate.Relocations.
      Where(c=>c.TimeIntervals.Select(d=>d.Start==sh.StartTime.Date).Any()).Any()** 
        select relocate.Relocations.Select(a=>a.Path.Items.
             Select(b=>b.DisplayString.Skip(4).SingleOrDefault()));
```

Comment: Adding Any() to the end does not resolve the issues it still shows the same error messages given above

Comment: .Any() should take care of error 1. Error 2 is probably what's left.

Comment: Adding Any() to the condition of the dates TimeIntervals.Any(d=>d.Start==sh.StartTime.Date)).Any() works but returns more than one result and is still IEnumerable

Comment: As I say in my answer, `relocate.Relocations.Where()` returns IEnumerable, but `relocate.Relocations.Where().Any()' returns boolean. I think you need to take care of your error 2. first. I have edited my answer slightly, adding another `Any()` to the nested `Where()`. Sorry about the trial-and-error :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply have to add a `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` at the end of the statement.